# How to remove "Deceased" entries from units list?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've butchered several kitten. There are no corpses to bury (I think, they all converted into skulls and skin). So I don't need anymore of listing them in Unit list. I'm using DF2010.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Nakilon!  We normally don't tag things like `kitten` and `unit-list` here because they can't mean the same things across the whole site.  Great question though.

Answer (score 3):

Without using some third-party tool that modified the game in memory, you can't. The unit list will contain everyone.

In recent versions (DF2012), the unit list has been split into tabs. One tab is set aside for all units which are missing/ghostly/deceased.

Comment: What dies in Murdered Circles stays in Murdered Circles.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't remove them with just normal Dwarf Fortress. I did some research, and I hear that [Runesmith](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=59056.0) might be able to. I've never used it personally. Page Up/Page Down are good enough for me.